# Convert a string date format "dd/MM/yyyy" into "dd-month-yyyy"

Tags: c#, asp.net

here, shift.frmfromdate ='{1/1/2015 12:00:00 AM}'. but, i want format 1-Jan-2015

```
protected void txttodate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    shift.frmfromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(txtfromdate.Text);
    shift.frmtodate = Convert.ToDateTime(txttodate.Text);
    gvshiftschdule.DataSource = shifthandler.shiftview(shift);
    gvshiftschdule.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: YOu can use the `.ToString("yourformat")` And if you are binding the data to the `Gridview` you can use the [DataFormatString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: But, am using html5 datetimepicker. i want date format 1-Jan-2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the string to your requirements.
here `dt` contains the input date.

**month/day numbers without/with leading zeroes**

`String.Format("{0:M/d/yyyy}", dt);`            // "3/9/2008"

`String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);`          // "03/09/2008"

**day/month names**

`String.Format("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}", dt);`    // "Sun, Mar 9, 2008"

`String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM d, yyyy}", dt);`  // "Sunday, March 9, 2008"

**two/four digit year**

`String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yy}", dt);`           // "03/09/08"

`String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", dt);`          // "03/09/2008"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy",ultureInfo.CurrentCulture)` But I am guessing by looking at your code, That you want to show the format on the `Gridview`. For that purpose the you can use the [DataFormatString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

On `gridview` you can do as ,

```
DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}
```

SO ultimatly your bound fields from `gridview` will look like,

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="frmfromdate" HeaderText="From Date" DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />
 <asp:BoundField DataField="frmDateTo" HeaderText="To Date" DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}" />
```